# Unremovable Keyboard Layout on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-layout

It seems that in a recent update a keyboard layout was added to my keyboard layout list, which is "Spanish (Mexico)". This layout doesn't appear on the Region & Language configuration tab.

Keyboard layout list:

[image: Keyboard layout list]

Region & Language:

[image: Region & Language]

It's really annoying, how can I remove it?

Comment: Did this happen after the update to build 1803?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it

Comment: I don't feel like it was so long ago, but perhaps. Anyways, that's not the same problem as mine, the newly added kb layout doesn't even appear in the Region & Language tab, but it does in the Layout Selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Import-Module -Name International -Force
$WinUserLangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $WinUserLangList -Force

Restart-Computer -Confirm -Force        #  !!! May be important !!!  #
```

Above PowerShell script *should* do the trick however I don't comprehend whether the last command `Restart-Computer` is really necessary (*sometimes* it's required to complete the job).

The extra input language(s) in the language bar could be identified using the `DISM` utility (Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool, *requires elevation*) in the `Active keyboard(s)` line as `DISM.exe /Online /Get-Intl`. Example:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Get-Intl | findstr /i "Active.keyboard"
```

> ```
> Active keyboard(s) : 0809:00000405, 0405:00000405, 0405:00020409, 0408:00010408, 0419:00020419, 041b:0000041b, 041f:0000041f, 041f:00000426, 0425:00000425, 0425:00010409, 0809:00000452
> ```

In fact, those values are stored under the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup
```

I wrote the following script to get a *human-legible* output instead of *dark and obscure* `0419:00020419`, `041b:0000041b`, …

```
$regBase = 'Registry::' + 
           'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts'
Function Get-Intl {
param( [string]$InputMethodTip )
    $auxlang, $auxKeyb = $InputMethodTip -split ':'
    $auxLangIn = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::
                    GetCultureInfo( [int]"0x$auxlang" ) # -band 0x3FF )
    [psCustomObject]@{
        InputMethodTip = $InputMethodTip
        Name           = $auxLangIn.Name
        # Autonym        = $WinUserLanguage.Autonym
        KbdLayoutName  = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name 'Layout Text' -Path (
                            Join-Path -Path $regBase -ChildPath $auxKeyb
                        ) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

'--- Get-WinUserLanguageList output:'
ForEach ( $WinUserLanguage in ( Get-WinUserLanguageList ) ) {
    $WinUserLanguage.InputMethodTips | ForEach-Object {
        Get-Intl -InputMethodTip $_
    }
}
'=== HKEY_USERS/DISM.EXE output:'
$regDefa = 'Registry::' + 
           'HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile'
# HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup
Get-ChildItem -Path $regDefa -Force | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property |
        Where-Object { $_ -match ':' } | 
            ForEach-Object {
                Get-Intl -InputMethodTip  $_
            }
```

**Output** (truncated):

```
D:\PShell\tests\InputMethodTip.ps1
```

> ```
> --- Get-WinUserLanguageList output:
>
> InputMethodTip Name  KbdLayoutName              
> -------------- ----  -------------              
> 0809:00000452  en-GB United Kingdom Extended    
> 0405:00000405  cs-CZ Czech                      
> 0405:00020409  cs-CZ United States-International
> 0408:00010408  el-GR Greek (220)                
> 0419:00020419  ru-RU Russian - Mnemonic         
> === HKEY_USERS/DISM.EXE output:
> 0809:00000452  en-GB United Kingdom Extended    
> 0405:00000405  cs-CZ Czech                      
> …
> ```