# Windows keyboard layout "ZZ" cannot be removed

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, locale

During some locale changes I've done, it seems like I accidently added the "ZZ" English (United Arab Emirates) keyboard layout.

I tried removing it in many ways, but it seems the layout does not appear in any settings menu nor windows registry.  Restarting the machine work help.

The language bar showing ZZ

[image]

Registry values for keyboard layouts (also checked Substitutes folder)

(40d is Hebrew, 809 and 409 are English US & UK)

[image: Registry values]

Windows language settings

[image: Windows Language settings]

I also checked inside Hebrew and English preferred languages for additional layout, but nothing there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unremovable Keyboard Layout on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1323000/unremovable-keyboard-layout-on-windows-10)

Comment: Check [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/) as well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by adding this UAE English manually and then removing it. Worked like a charm.